# Image Property in Google App Engine with Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I have a Card Class.

```
class Card(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    image = '''insert property here'''
    description = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    submitted = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

How do I add an image to the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For binary data, you can use a `BlobProperty` (see docs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#Blob)), making your code:

```
class Card(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    image = db.BlobProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    submitted = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

You could then assign to your property as follows (assuming your image parameter from a user form is `image`; if not using a form, you can treat the image like you would other binary data):

```
my_card = Card()
# Other properties defined here...
my_image = self.request.get('image')
card.image = db.Blob(my_image)
my_card.put()
```

Comment: @RohitRayudu No problem at all, hope it helps!